# Non-repudiation in classical cryptosystem

Tags: symmetric, non-repudiation

How can we modify classical cryptography system to provide non-repudiation?

I want to ensure non-repudiation in symmetric key cryptography so that we can find out who is sender of a particular message.As sender and receiver share the same key, we can't find out who the sender was.

Comment: Have both sides use hash based signatures to sign their messages?

Comment: Either yes or no both will work. You can answer from any perspective.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you fully understand what poncho is meaning. I think he is referring to [hash based signatures](https://www.cdc.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/~dahmen/papers/hashbasedcrypto.pdf), which turn hashes into proper asymmetric digital signatures.

Comment: Okay. No, both the sides have not used hash based signatures to sign their messages.